# Directional derivative Df v

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

$f(x,y)= \sqrt{x^2+y^3}$

$P_0 (0,0)$

$\vec{v}=  (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$

Why does the directional derivative Df v not exist?

Her gradient is $ (0,0) $ there is no

$ \frac {2x} {\sqrt {x ^ 2 + y ^ 2}} $ is the x coordinate of the gradient

Comment: Because $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$

Comment: Your function $f$ has no derivative on $(0,0)$, no matter what direction you take.

Comment: @Dayton: I can give you lots of functions which are not differentiable at $(0,0)$ and yet still have directional derivatives in every direction. So be careful.

Comment: Your post seems incomplete. Even $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)$ does not exist. But you must write down the *definition*, not use formulas.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes you are correct, $\nabla_u f(x) = \nabla_xf(x)\cdot u$ only when $f$ is differentiable... I naively forgot the correct definition $\nabla_uf(x) := \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+uh) - f(x)}{h}$ when the limit exists